# CALayer memory management ram

Tags: ios, xcode

I have more than 60 UIImageViews, and to each of them I apply a CLlayer in the following way:

```
image1.layer.cornerRadius = 6.0;
                image1.layer.masksToBounds = YES;
```

How much memory does CLLayer use? Since I do it to contain the image subviews in the image (not visible outside the image, while visible without applying the layer), is it better to remove it and use another code? if so which?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let the system worry about memory management. 60 views is not so many (6000 might be). Each UIImageView is backed by a UIImage and a CGImageRef, and the system can purge the CGImageRef as needed to make space since it can reload it using cached info in the UIImage.

If you want to profile your memory usage, then use ObjectAlloc in Instruments - if you just use all Instruments defaults you will still get a lot of useful information.